# Built in function/ easy way to see if structure is a piecewise-polynomial?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I want a function that takes a variable as input and returns 1 if the variable is ppform and 0 if it isn't. Since ppforms in MATLAB are structures, but not all structures are ppform, I see no way to use `isa` to do this.

I could of course write a function to check if a given variable is a structure, has the right fields, and that the fields themselves are of the right form, but I'm just wondering if MATLAB has a built in function that can do this? Google and the MATHWORKS website have not helped me here.

Answer (score 1):

Given your variable `pp`, you can check that it's a structure *and has the appropriate fields*:

```
isstruct(pp) & isequal(fields(pp), {'form' 'breaks' 'coefs' 'pieces' 'order' 'dim'}.')
```

Note that this doesn't check that the fields' contents are of the appropriate type (for example, the field `form` should contain a string) or have the permitted values.

Comment: Yes, this is true and in fact can be shortened a bit by writing: `isstruct(pp) & isfield(pp,{'form','dim','pieces','breaks','coefs','order'})`. But as you say, it doesn't check the fields' contents.

Comment: @Delyle But that doesn't check that there are no extra fields

Comment: True, but if there are extra fields you'll still be able to evaluate `pp` in any function that takes in ppform structures as input.

Comment: @Delyle Hm. Good point! The question is then: how do we _define_ what is a pp-struct and what isn't? Are extra fields allowed?